# progressDialoge does not show the current incremented progress?

Tags: android, progressdialog

Why the `progressdialoge` is not showing the incremented progress?
what i missed in the below code?

Java_Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_progress_dialoge_test00);

    mProgreeDialoge = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mHandler = new Handler();
}

public void open(View view) {
    mProgreeDialoge.setTitle("Progress Dialoge Box");
    mProgreeDialoge.setMessage("Downloading...");
    mProgreeDialoge.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mProgreeDialoge.setProgress(0);
    mProgreeDialoge.setMax(20);
    mProgreeDialoge.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgreeDialoge.show();


    final Thread mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (mProgreeDialoge.getProgress() <= mProgreeDialoge.getMax() ) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            mProgreeDialoge.incrementProgressBy(2);
                        }
                    });

                    if (mProgreeDialoge.getProgress() == mProgreeDialoge.getMax() ) {
                        mProgreeDialoge.dismiss();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });
    mThread.start();
```

Comment: See this tutorial. It will help you to understand the concept http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/progressdialog/android-progressdialog-example/

Comment: I followed also another tutorial, but the increasing progress steps are not show. always set to 0/20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default mode of ProgressDialoge is indeterminate .it means it shows the cyclic animation. This mode is useful when you do not have clear indication of when particular task will be completed. I think, that's why the incremented progress is not shown.
[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) you will find `progressdialog` methods and constants

in your case, try this: `mProgreeDialoge.setIndeterminate(false);`

Answer (score 0):

Just do one small change in your code. Remove this line `mProgreeDialoge.setIndeterminate(true)` or set it to false.